Apk file is not building in android studio
I have stucked on an error form last few days and i don't know how to solve it.
I tried a lot to solve this, but failed.
When i am building apk file it shows error but gradle sync done successfully.
the unknown deoendencies is already present in github.
Thanks in advance for helping.
(https://i.sstatic.net/BWMBVnzu.png)

I recommend that you provide a [mcve]. In this case, this would include your Gradle files where you are requesting that dependency and your Gradle configuration for which repositories it should use for such dependencies.
